# How to display a specific field instead of Title with Entity Reference

Tags: entities

I Have two entities.

```
**Students** 
Title
Body

**Cours**
Title
Body
CoursRefNumber
```

I can associate many Cours for each students.
To do that, I create a Entity Reference on Cours for student.

When I create a new Student, I see al the Available Cours List.
Instead of showing Title In the Listbox, How can I display the CoursRefNumber .

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you edit your entity reference field you'll see an "Entity Selection" fieldset section. There is a "Mode" field in there that defaults to "Simple" which just lists the entity titles.  You can change that to "Views" which lets you use a custom View to display the selection.

You'll want to create a View first. Just create the View to display the fields you want.  That could be the Cours Title and CoursRefNumber if you want.